# localStorage 'storage' event firing with null event.key

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I noticed that sometimes the `storage` event gets fired with an `event.key` of `null`. When/why does this happen?

Comment: @nikhil http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @all - I was unaware about this. Thank you for bringing this up! I have deleted the remark and down-vote

Answer (score 1):

According to [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-event), the `storage` event is fired with a `event.key` of `null` when `clear` has been called:

> Otherwise, if the event is being fired due to an invocation of the clear() method, the event must have its key, oldValue, and newValue attributes initialized to null.